# why printf prints same value as the value above it?

Tags: c, printf

```c
int main(void)
{
    int a = 65;
    char c = (char)a;

    printf("%c\n", c);              // output: A
    printf("%f\n", (float)a);       // output: 65.000000
    printf("%f\n", 5/2);            // output: 65.000000 why???


    return 0;
}
//why printf("%f\n", 5/2); prints same number as a number above????
```

it supposed to print 2.5, i want to know why it doesn't prints this number and what's happens bts?
i tried to find answers on google but i'm not sure how to question this problem

Comment: What compiler/platform do you use? I get different results.

Comment: `5/2` is `int`, not `double`, which `printf` expects with a `%f` specifier. In short, you're lying to `printf` when you said "I'm going to send you a `double`."

Comment: i use notepad++, and gcc

Comment: `printf("%c\n", c);              // output: A` <<-- I dont believe this

Comment: @WhozCraig is the fact that I am getting `30.0000` the result of undefined behavior then?

Comment: oh wait i pasted the wrong code, just switch a = 30 to a = 65

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/M3ysha

Comment: @BartFriederichs Per C11 7.21.6.1p9, if you send a mismatch of format specifier to argument type, you invoke UB.

Comment: ok i got that 5/2 is 2 and %f expecting a float, but does it takes the float above because %f ignoring integers so it takes the closest float above? i mean is it true to say that?

Comment: @Rebel Why does it take the float above? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59008476/why-printf-prints-same-value-as-the-value-above-it/59008838#59008838).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simplified and not necessarily perfectly accurate answer, but: When you use `%f` in a `printf` format statement, it does *not* mean "take the next argument that was passed, and print it as a float".  No, instead what it means is "take the next float argument that was passed, and print it."  But in your third `printf` call, there *was* no float argument that was passed (because `5/2` gives the `int` value 2).  So when `printf` went to look in the place where float arguments are passed, by chance it picked up the last actual floating-point number you had passed, even though it was passed by the previous `printf` call.

This is not guaranteed to happen, and obviously it's not the sort of thing you'd want to depend on, but it explains why you saw what you saw.

Good compilers help you avoid this kind of mistake by warning you when the number or type of your `printf` arguments do not match the format string.  For example, mine says

```
warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int'
```

If your compiler doesn't know how to print warnings like these, you might like to try to find a better one.

Comment: ooh, okay thanks. 
by the way in my course we are working with this compiler so i can't change, but thanks for making it clear to me now.

Answer (score 3):

you have the UB in that code. in the third printf - you pass integer but printf expects double - UB

cast it and it will work correctly
https://godbolt.org/z/M3ysha

Answer (score 0):

5 and 2 are integers, 5/2 is a integer too and truncated to the next int which is 2

try to cast (double)(5/2)

or use 5.0 / 2.0

Comment: ok, i got how to fix that, but i still don't get why it takes the number abover exactly?

Comment: @Rebel see answer of user P__J__ and open the link, then remove `(double)` from last `printf` and see changes in assembler

Answer (score 0):

- C compiler is computing `5 / 2` as an integer: 5 / 2 -> 2.
- `ptinf()` is expecting a `%f`.
- A buggy cast from int[2] to float[?] on your machine / os / compiler / libc is 30.00000, which `printf` loyally prints.

To demonstrate this we can use a bigger number, 5000 / 3 for instance. You should properly cast your data, or use the proper literals 5.0 instead of 5.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("5/3 d:\t\t\t %d\n", 5/3);
  // printf("5/3 n:\t\t\t %n\n", 5/3); // segfault
  printf("5/3 f:\t\t\t %f\n", 5/3);

  printf("(double) 5/3 d:\t\t %d \n", (double) 5/3);
  // printf("(double) 5/3 n:\t\t %n \n", (double) 5/3); // memory corruption
  printf("(double) 5/3 f:\t\t %f \n", (double) 5/3);

  printf("(float) 5/3 d:\t\t %d \n", (float) 5/3);
  // printf("(float) 5/3 n:\t\t %n \n", (float) 5/3); // memory corruption
  printf("(float) 5/3 f:\t\t %f \n", (float) 5/3);

  printf("5/3 d:\t\t\t %d \n", 5000/3);
  // printf("5/3 n:\t\t\t %n \n", 5000/3); // segfault
  printf("5/3 f:\t\t\t %f \n", 5000/3);

  printf("5./3. d:\t\t %d \n", 5./3.);
  // printf("5./3. n:\t\t %n \n", 5./3.); // memory corruption
  printf("5./3. f:\t\t %f \n", 5./3.);

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
5/3 d:           1
5/3 f:           0.000000
(double) 5/3 d:      33989216 
(double) 5/3 f:      1.666667 
(float) 5/3 d:       33989216 
(float) 5/3 f:       1.666667 
5/3 d:           1666 
5/3 f:           1.666667 
5./3. d:         33989216 
5./3. f:         1.666667
```

So, it doesn't matter if it's 5/2 or something else, what matters is the data type. In your case, the chain of casts: `(float) (int) 5/2 = 1` accidentally happens to be equals to 30.0000 float.

Also, feeding 2 or 4 bytes integer into printf and telling it to expect 8 bytes (such as passing int and formatting as double), hopefully you'll get a segfault, if you're unlucky enough you'll get memory corruption and hard to track bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is due to the way arguments are passed to functions.

For e.g., integer values are passed via registers like edx, esi etc. (as long as the arguments fit in available registers).  However, floating point arguments are passed in xmm* registers (as long as they fit in available registers).

So inside the function, the values are fetched from appropriate registers based on the type specifier.  So a `%d` would fetch from `edx`/`esi` etc, and `%f` would fetch from `xmm*` registers.

In your case, the line `printf("%f\n", (float)a);` stored the value of `a` (which is 65) as a real value `65.0` due to typecasting.  As a result, `xxm0` register will have value 65.0.

Now when the control came to `printf("%f\n", 5/2);`, the function argument `5/2` is an integer.  So it doesn't get pushed into `xxm0` register. However since `%f` expects a value in `xxm*` (in this case `xxm0`) register, it just retries whatever value is there in xxm0.  In your case, `xxm0` had stored the value 65.0 from earlier `printf()` call.  So 65.0 is printed.

The below program should make it more clear:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", 10, 11.1, 12.2, 40);       // 11.100000
    printf("%f %f\n", 5/2, 1, 2, 3, 4);       // 11.100000 12.200000
}
```

During first `printf()` call, `xxm0 = 11.1` and `xxm1 = 12.2`.  Since all of the arguments in the second `printf()` evaluate to be integers, so nothing gets stored in `xxm*` registers (which also means old values of `xxm*` registers remain unaltered).  Since `%f` expects real numbers to be in `xxm*` registers, it just prints whatever values they hold (in this case values from first `printf()` statement).

You can use https://www.godbolt.org to see the generated assembly code.